# Discord bot client.guilds.cache.size doesnt work

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want my bot to send a embed with number of servers that the bot is in with 'client.guilds.cache.size' but it always says in the embed that its in 0 server
Here is my code:

````
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
    ]
});

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is ready!  Currently in ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers.');
});

module.exports = {
    data: {
        name: 'botinfo',
        description: "View RSHL bot information",
    },
    async execute(interaction) {
        const fs = require('fs');

        const folderPath = './commands'; // Đường dẫn của thư mục "commands"

        fs.readdir(folderPath, (err, files) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Lỗi khi đọc thư mục:', err);
                return;
            }
            const numberOfFilesInFolder = files.length;
            const botinfoEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor(0x333DAA)
            .setTitle('Real Soccer HaxBall League')
            .setURL('https://discord.gg/vietnam-real-soccer-league-vpl-2023-997475534621659186')
            .setAuthor({ name: 'RSHL', iconURL: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1145003277654708245/1145003388824719441/VPL-LOGO-WITH-BACKGR.png' })
            .addFields(
                    { name: 'Developer', value: '```ducday.rshl```' },
                    { name: 'Language', value: '```Javascript```', inline: true },
                    { name: 'Server', value: `\`\`\`${client.guilds.cache.size}\`\`\``, inline: true },
                    { name: 'Commands', value: `\`\`\`${numberOfFilesInFolder}\`\`\``, inline: true },
                    { name: 'Created on (DD/MM/YYYY)', value: '```3/7/2023```' }
                )
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter({ text: 'RSHL', iconURL: 'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1145003277654708245/1145003387247657072/VPL.png?width=631&height=473' });

            interaction.reply({ embeds: [botinfoEmbed] });
        });
    }
}
````

I try to do many things in order to fix it but i cant, hope that you guys can help me with this!

Comment: Your cache is empty. Try fetching your guilds first by adding `await client.guilds.fetch()` before your embed